# Jquery Mobile + Phonegap + Wordpress = Native App

Tags: wordpress, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am currently planning to create a mood tracking application that will be able to run in different kinds of mobile platforms and I think Phonegap will be the best choice for that. But having no background in PHP coding and anything else with regards to database handling, I wanted to integrate Wordpress with my "native app". (So I could use various kinds of plugins to make my coding more easier) Is this possible? I've already read different kinds of articles and blogs but I want it to be straight forward as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely possible - I'm actually working on a project where we're doing this right now. But without having a background in PHP you're going to struggle. Do you know any PHP/are you planning to learn any?

Answer (score 0):

Use Wordpress as administration system on a Phonegap app is an easy way to have a great post system and widget options. But, if you have no background in PHP it's a little bit more complex...

To access to your WP datas, you'll need to write some PHP scripts that retrieve these datas to your application.

Take a look to this tutorial, I should help http://alexbachuk.com/wordpress-and-phonegap-part-1/

Good luck !